# Suppose f, g : D → R are continuous on D and that g(x) does not = 0 for all x ∈ D. Give an ε-δ proof that their quotient f/g is continuous on D

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$, $g : D → R$ are continuous on $D$ and that $g(x)$ does not $ =0$ for all $ x ∈ D$. Give an $ε-δ$ proof that their quotient $f/g$ is continuous on $D$.

I know that I need to use the definition of continuity for this problem but am having trouble getting the following into a form that I can substitute the epsilons.
$|((f(x)-f(a))/(g(x)-g(a))|$

Comment: Have you seen the proof for multiplication of functions? One of the steps in the proof is "clever," a non-obvious way to add 0 (usually phrased this way, perhaps the proof you know is different); you will need a similar idea here.

Answer (score 0):

Start from what you need to prove: For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that

$$\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - \frac{f(a)}{g(a)}\right| < \epsilon, \space \space |x-a| < \delta$$

$$\implies \left|\frac{f(x)g(a) - g(x)f(a)}{g(a)g(x)}\right| < \epsilon$$

Now, since we know that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are individually continuous at $a$ - see if you can manipulate this numerator to get you terms of $|f(x)-f(a)|$ and $|g(x)-g(a)|$ (adding and subtracting certain terms?)

Then you know that those differences are bounded by some other $\epsilon'$ and $\epsilon''$ - substitute and use the triangle inequality to get that upper bound to prove continuity

Comment: This was very helpful! I was able to manipulate the numerator correctly but am stuck on what to do with the denominator now.

Comment: @user921157 Try using the fact that $|g(x)-g(a)|<\varepsilon\Longleftrightarrow g(a)-\varepsilon<g(x)<g(a)+\varepsilon$ to get a lower bound on $|g(x)|$.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the product of continuous functions is continuous, then all you really need to show is that if $g:D\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and does not vanish on $D$, then $h:D\to\mathbb{R}$ where $h(x)=1/g(x)$ is continuous.

If you really want to leverage some theorems, then you just need to show that $i:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $i(x)=1/x$ is continuous (using epsilon-delta definition). This is because if $g:D\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous, non-vanishing function, then it is either strictly positive or strictly negative (if it had both positive and negative values, think about the IVT to show why this can't happen if $g$ does not vanish).

Then you use the fact that composition of continuous functions is continuous to get that $h(x) = (i\circ g)(x)=1/g(x)$ is continuous. Then, since the product of continuous functions is continuous, the function $f\cdot h:D\to\mathbb{R}$ where $(f\cdot h)(x)=f(x)h(x)$ is continuous.